# Meaning of おま言う

Tags: internet-slang

On the Internet, two persons [talk about spying and open source](http://opensource.slashdot.jp/comments.pl?sid=603358&cid=2400351):

> A: 秘密をなくして、全部さらけ出せよ。そっちのほうがオープンだぞw
>   B: おま言う

What does B want to express?
I thought it was a typo but there [seems to be many people using this expression](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%8A%E3%81%BE%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%22).

Full context: http://opensource.slashdot.jp/story/13/06/12/069203

Other examples:

```
本日のおま言うスレ
ただ天おま言う
おま言う速報
```

Not a single dictionary in the first 2 pages of Google results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the 3rd Google page I have found [this blog post](http://zodiacempathy.blog.fc2.com/blog-date-20130601.html) that has more information:

> 僕が言ってもそうなんだけど、最近いわゆる「おま言う」が多すぎて。
>   テレビ見てたり、文章読んでたり、はたまたツイッターの書き込みを覗いたり。
>   この世には「おま言う」、つまり「お前が言うな」が多すぎて、僕も出来るだけそう思われない生き方をしなくちゃならないなと思った。

So おま言う is the abbreviation of お前が言うな.

Thanks to oldergod for pointing out that the meaning is: 'shut up, you are not in a position to say this'

Comment: You are right for the おま言う is お前が言うな but then ??? It simply means 'shut up, you are not in position to say this'. Nothing to do with the veracity of the thing said.